# Help me make a sentence with a figurative meaning

Tags: metaphors

> But everything will shatter when life puts into one equation a great problem, ambitions and a million of dollars. And this story won't be about mathematics.

I am trying to describe the life of one mathematician. He solved a great problem and was awarded a million dollars for it. But there were a lot of scandals, disappointments. He refused the prize and everything was bleak.

I am using figurative speech and it sounds fine in my language, but what about English? Of course, the equation mentioned is imaginary, it is just a way to say that his life changed when all those things got mixed up in his life. And since it is about mathematics, I used an equation as a figurative object.

Comment: I'm trying hard to understand the sentence!

Comment: @MaulikV Can you understand the unshifted version?  "But everything will shatter when life puts [ a great problem, ambition and a million dollars ] into one equation."

Comment: @snailplane Okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence seems fine to me, but I am (this is just a personal style-issue, I guess) a bit thrown off by the fact that the problem and the dollars are specified, but the ambitions stand alone. The three parts would flow better by adding something to the ambition(s) like this:

Also, I would say "a million dollars", not "a million *of* dollars" - or possible "*one* million dollars".

Not sure why - I *would* say "millions *of* dollars" if that were applicable.

> But everything will shatter when life puts into one equation a great problem, burning ambition and a million dollars.

I assume it is a matter of taste, I leave the consideration up to the author. :)

Comment: What do you mean by the ambitions are not specified? I didn't use an adjective with the ambitions?

Comment: Yes, they are a bit "left on their own", I feel. _great_ problem, _a million_ dollars, but "just" ambitions.

Comment: You wouldn't shift 'into one equation' to the end of the sentence, like snailplane did in the comments?

Comment: Sorry, there was just one million :) Otherwise we exaggerate.

Comment: I like it where it is, actually - although snailplane's version is _easier_ to understand, I don't _enjoy_ it as much :)

Comment: @Graduate My version was just to show the sentence in its basic word order in case it helped Maulik understand.  Your version is the shifted one.  (It's fine.)